# The server cannot started because one or more of the ports are invalid [Tomcat in Eclipse]

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

When I open my file list-student.jsp. I experienced the following error:

> Starting Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost has encountered a problem. The server cannot be started because one or more of the ports are invalid. Open the server editor and correct invalid ports.

I tried to go server tab and change the port from 8080 to different number, but it doesn't work. I had the same problem before and I changed 8080 to another number liked 8181 and it worked, but today, even I tried to change port number and the problem can't be fixed.

[image: Changing port number]

Comment: 'Invalid' isn't the same thing as 'in use'. Something wrong with your web.xml. Off topic.

Comment: Hi there, i don't know what problems happened, so decided to deleted the server and set up a new one. Everything works fine now. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The issue is that the Tomcat admin port was not defined. You need to have it as an actual number such as `9000` rather than as a hyphen `-`.

[image: Tomcat 9 configuration page (Eclipse)]

Comment: experienced the same. who's decision think this is a great idea to make the default port a hyphen. "yeah, lets make millions of developer pain right starting tomcat"

Comment: Why to define an admin port? Moreover, in the server.xml it doesn't even is called that way. When the change put forward is done a "<Server" tag is added to that file.

Answer (score 24):

This issue came in Tomcat 9 version starting from Eclipse.

```
The server cannot started because one or more of the ports are invalid
```

Only Modify the server ports "Tomcat Admin Port"  default value from hyphen (-)  to zero(0)  it's working fine.

[image]

Comment: and restart the tomcat

Answer (score 15):

This is because the tomcat admin port or any other port was not defined.

[image]

Click ok and open the tomcat server at localhost.

[image]

In the highlighted area, if the port number is not defined then give it a port number, save the file and run again.

Comment: I see you are coming from Chad Derby course on Udemy. I was stuck at same point :)

Answer (score 12):

This is how i fixed this :
Go to **Eclipse** => **Window** => **Show View** => **Servers** => *DoubleClick on* **Tomcat Server** => Change admin port to "1" and leave the HTTP port to "8080" . Make sure to kill any processes which are running on port 8080.You will find your project on **localhost:8080/java project name**  , if you don't add java project name it will give you error 404. Hope this works !

Comment: Thanks for providing the path to the Overview view that others have shown the solution!

Comment: Thanks for the path. While others have provided a solution, I was clueless where to find overview page.

Answer (score 3):

What is did is : Eclipse->Window ->Show View->Servers->DoubleClick on Tomcat Server-> Change admin port to "1" and leave the HTTP port to "8081" . Make sure to kill any processes which are running on port 8080. You will find your project on localhost:8081/java project name, worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

go to this location  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf`

and copy `server.xml` file and paste on desktop

open `server.xml` from desktop just change `-1` to `1` at following tag

```
<Server port="1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add available port number in `Tomcat admin port` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add my two cents.  I installed Apache Tomcat 10.0 and had the same issue in Eclipse.  I change the - for the Admin port and everything worked fine afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, navigate to Window -> Show View -> Servers. A new tab pane entitled 'Servers' should appear (at the bottom) on the screen. Double click on your instance of Tomcat and a pane entitled 'Overview' should open (above). On the right side of this should be a pane entitled 'Ports'. I set the Tomcat admin port = 1. Now, right click on your Tomcat instance in the 'Servers' tab pane and select the start option. If this works the status of the Tomcat instance will change from stopped to running. In my case I was warned that port 8080 was in use (by an instance of Tomcat running outside of Eclipse). You have two options here. Run the Windows Services manager dialog and stop the Tomcat instance using port 8080, or go back to the 'Ports' pane in Eclipse and set the port to 8081. I went for the latter option, and was able to start Tomcat within Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If using Spring-Tools v4 IDE you can open Tomcat setting:

Window -> Show View -> Server

or

Window -> Show View -> Other -> Server -> Servers (double-click)

Bottom menu must show "Servers" menu...

[image]

Double click on "Tomcat v8xx" in the menu...

Edit the "Tomcat admin port"  replace  the - character with 1

[image]

Close and Save the changes and restart IDE. Tomcat must be started by the app calling it not manually

Answer (score 0):

- Open cmd and type ***netstat -a***
- Find port ***8080*** is running or not
- Open "windows defender firewall with advanced security" and select Inbound Rules *next* new Rule *next* select "Port" *next* Specific local ports: 8080 *next* select Block the connection *next* type a name and finish, now restart your system.
- Open ***Services.msc*** find Apache Tomcat V.x and stop it.

**That's it**

Answer (score 0):

declare all undeclared ports in the server window, and save.

Answer (score 0):

In the server folder find the server.xml file and change the following

to

```
<Server port="1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

and

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

to

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double click the Tomcat server and in overview window set available ports numbers to Tomcat admin port and HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 0):

I really thank the person who came with idea of reconfiguring the admoinistration port as follows
PortNmae         Port number
Tomcat           9000
HTTP/1.1         9090
AJP/1.3          9000
This configuration worked smoothly for me

Comment: Would you please review and add formatting to make this answer clear?

Answer (score 0):

I gave a lot of time on this one.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV6fv.png)

Double Click on **highlighted area(Tomcatv9.0)**-->change **Tomcat admin port to 1** && **HTTP/1.1 to 8081**

this should work :)

Answer (score -1):

I have been solving this issue with trial n error and come with the solution

Right click on server tap on open/F3 change your port to anything but not - (hyphen).  If it still showing error try another one by adding one no. To the port no. And its done